# django, sorl-thumbnail оптимизация запросов

Tags: python, django

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой оптимизации запросов кеширования. Картинки изменяю через sorl-thumbnail. Если зайти в браузер с чистым кэшем сессии, то обнаруживаю подобную картину.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6 запросов на кеширование каждой из картинок. Можно ли это как либо оптимизировать queryset'ами или чем либо другим?

В `models.py`

```
@property
def photo_detail(self):
    if self.photo:
        return sorl.thumbnail.get_thumbnail(
            self.photo, "200x200", crop="center"
        )
    return None
```

во `views.py` пробовал как этот метод

```
{% thumbnail cat.photo "800x800" crop="center" as photo %}
   <img src="{{ photo.url }}" width="180px">
{% endthumbnail %}
введите сюда код
```

так и
`<img src="{{ photo.photo_detail }}" width="180px">`

P.S
Если удалить кэш и почистить
`python manage.py thumbnail cleanup`

то кол-во запросов для кеширования 6 картинок становится каким-то фантастическим числом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть подозрение, что ответ на вопрос будет «хз» https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail/issues/668

Comment: да, это здорово :D Но, если я буду использовать условно 100 картинок на одной странице(условно), какое же потребление времени на отгрузку страницы будет?! При последующих запросах все в порядке, так как в кэш сессии подгружается информация, но вот что будет с юзером который первый раз зашел на сайт, минута ожидания?

Comment: Если для вас основной проблемой является именно процесс генерации миниатюры, то можно попробовать запросить миниатюру [через python-код](https://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#low-level-api-examples) когда-нибудь заранее (например, в админке в момент создания/редактирования картинки или типа того)

Comment: В этом проблемы нет, я специально прикрепил функцию `photo_detail` вся проблема в оптимизации запросов

Comment: А вы не забываете вызывать этот самый photo_detail «когда-нибудь заранее» как я предложил?

Comment: В данном случае это не поможет, так как все равно будет n "похожих" запросов
`SELECT "thumbnail_kvstore"."key",
       "thumbnail_kvstore"."value"
  FROM "thumbnail_kvstore"
 WHERE "thumbnail_kvstore"."key" = '''sorl-thumbnail||image||fc347cbc22d1ab853d151845e507962c'''` 
ведется сравнение по значению, а не выборка элементов

Comment: На ваших скриншотах видно, что они занимают буквально 0 времени, так что это не должно быть проблемой